# How to slice pandas dataframe based on attribute of column name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where the column names are datatime objects like this:

```
            17:02:00    17:03:00 ...    
2017-09-18  1236.0      463.0   
2017-09-19  791.0       476.0   
2017-09-20  2086.0      988.0
```

How can I select a slice of the dataframe based on the column name values like this pseudo code:

```
df_slice = df.column_name >= datetime.time(8, 30) & df.column_name < datetime.time(9, 0)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need first convert values to `times` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) + [`time`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.time.html) and then select columns by condition:

```
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).time

df_slice = df.loc[:, (df.columns >= datetime.time(8, 30)) & 
                     (df.columns < datetime.time(9, 0))]
```

Sample:

```
print (df)
            17:02:00  08:45:00
2017-09-18    1236.0     463.0
2017-09-19     791.0     476.0
2017-09-20    2086.0     988.0

df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).time

df_slice = df.loc[:, (df.columns >= datetime.time(8, 30)) & 
                     (df.columns < datetime.time(9, 0))]

print (df_slice)
            08:45:00
2017-09-18     463.0
2017-09-19     476.0
2017-09-20     988.0
```

Thank you `@Zero` for simplify answer:

```
df.loc[:, (df.columns > '08:30:00') & (df.columns < '09:00:00')]
```

Comment: I get TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= datetime.time()

Comment: Assuming column are still string, you could do `df.loc[:, (df.columns > '08:30:00') & (df.columns < '09:00:00')]` =)

Answer (score 1):

I would say something like:

```
from datetime import datetime 

to_dt = lambda x : datetime.strptime(x, '%H:%M:%S')

time_1 = to_dt('08:30:00')
time_2 = to_dt('09:00:00')

cols_to_use = [
    i for i in df.columns if 
        to_dt(i) >= time_1 and 
        to_dt(i) <= time_2
]

df_slice = df.loc[:, cols_to_use]
```

So in other words all the comparison is happening outside of pandas.  I'm sure this could be done as a one-liner but I've spaced it out a bit to make it easier to read.

Comment: I get: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: Added the missing `import` and reorganized the code.